# Creating a 360 degrees image turntable viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, image, ios

I want to create a 360 degree turntable showing lots of pictures (12, 24 or 36) by controlling that rotation with touch events (like that [example](http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/threesixty.php)  but coded for an iOS app natively).

The simplest idea depending on the touch position is to load that specific uiimage.
Any ideas what's the best practice for that? Is there a chance to create that image-turntable with the help of coreanimation faster? Any other hints on that? Any other projects known where I can get some help on that?

Thanks for your time and hints in the right direction.

Here's another example for an ipad-app from the "[audi a8](http://www.audiusa.com/us/brand/en/models/a8/explore/the_new_a8_ipad_app.html)".

Comment: "Any other projects known where I can get some help on that?" - Have you got one? I need the same....

Answer (score 2):

From the first example it becomes obvious that the objects have actually been photographed for each angle of rotation. This is the really tricky part. You will need a tripod and a camera with remote control, and if possible also a rotational platter to keep angles consistent.

Implementation is relatively straightforward. As you guessed, you just track the touch positions and, depending on delta to the last touch position, show the appropriate image.

Comment: Yep... the photography is going to be 90% of the effort.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can just use the HTML/CSS/JS used in the same example... just load that in an UIWebView in your app and load your site embedded as a resource...

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIImageView, load array of your frames, handle tap movement over the screen y-axis and change active image accordingly. Don't forget to loop your images. :)

Comment: What's the rationale for subclassing UIImageView rather than just setting the UIImageView's image property?

Comment: it perfectly work for image animations out of the box. And there is way to load array of images. And you could reuse this subclass many times. Without rewriting the same code for setting images into UIImageView.